# Why Android xml layout file doesn't recognize content assist by ctrl+space?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

I am facing problem with eclipse that is when I am using the Android xml layout file to design a screen, I try to add attribute to an element that I have already created. I used to type two letters of the attribute then tap ctrl+space so it will show list of all available attribute by IntelliSense. Now it is not showing anything, instead it is showing a message at the bottom of the screen like below image.

Anybody faced the problem and solved it?

Appreciate your help because it is slowing down my work.

[image]

Comment: Could you copy/paste all the xml code of that file? I will try it out then.

Comment: It doesn't relate to a specific xml layout file it is for all of them

Comment: mmm... then I don't know, sorry. you can always try to update and restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer Updated:**

Here it goes,

I guess you are trying to access `Parameter Hints (Ctrl+Shift+Space)` Instead of Default `Content Assist (Ctrl+Space)`.

1. If we press `(Ctrl+Shift+Space)` in the java file it will gives you the detailed parameter description with the particular list of method names.
2. If we press `(Ctrl+Shift+Space)` in the xml file , it will gives the following errors,

   (a.) Element  or  or anything is unknown.

   (b.) Content assist not available at the current location.

   (c.) No completions available.

**Old Answer:**

According to the **Eclipse content assist** documents ,

the `Element Unknown` errors are because of,

The `Element`, we are looking for is not defined `in-scope schema definitions`.

`XML Content Assist` will be loaded from the `schema` files and the belonging `xml` file descriptions.

So mostly no chances to be missed `Elements` in `android sdk`.

Check whether any thing missed out in the following `preferences`,

**Window-preferences-XML-XML Files-Editor- Content Assist**   Check the `priorities` or **reset** it.

I guess, You may missed somewhere, because i noticed that in your attached image,

**`Graphical Layout.xml`** is your layout name. It cannot be named like that,
In `android` , it should be **without any space** and should **"Starts with lower case"**.

If you give the **detailed** **error report**, then it is possible for somebody to tackle it.

You mentioned that , for all of the `layout` files you are getting the same error,
so you can create a simple sample layout and paste with your question.

So my suggestion is, please check whether do you went wrong in somewhere in the xml file by
defining and providing open with priorities or not.

And do check the `XML Content Assist` in the **Window-Preferences** menu.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Actually I used the following: from the   Content Assist page I changed Suggestion strategy from strict to lax then it worked. I don't know if it was the point. And according to xml file naming it I've just change it on paint :)

Answer (score 1):

( No pun or ecipse bashing intendet ) 
There is a lot of grounds for eclipse chocking on some files, and almost never solution - you just hope  that it works.  For android I would recommend you to switch to IDEA -  android plugins are contrained in free community edition and work like a charm ( and shall be  there a problem, jetbrains support usually provides useful and  correct answers in  couple of hours )

There is even previews mode for UIs which updates as you type allows you to extract themes and whatever.